# Mongo connector error: Unable to process oplog document

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, py2neo

I am new to neo4j-doc-manager and I am trying to use neo4j-doc-manager to view the collection from my mongoDB to a created graph in neo4j as per:
**https://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/**

I've have my mongoDB and neo4j instance running in local and I'm using the following command:

```
mongo-connector -m mongodb://localhost:27017/axa -t 
  http://<user_name>:
  <password>@localhost:7474/C:/Users/user_name/.Ne
  o4jDesktop/neo4jDatabases/database-c791fa15-9a0d-4051-bb1f- 
  316ec9f1c7df/installation-4.0.3/data/ -d neo4j_doc_manager
```

However I get an error:

```
2020-04-17 15:49:47,011 [ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:309 - **Unable to process oplog document** {'ts': Timestamp(1587118784, 2), 't': 9, 'h': 0, 'v': 2, 'op': 'i', 'ns': 'axa.talks', 'ui': UUID('3245621e-e204-49fc-8350-d9950246fa6c'), 'wall': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 10, 19, 44, 994000), 'o': {'session': {'title': '12 Years of Spring: An Open Source Journey', 'abstract': 'Spring emerged as a core open source project in early 2003 and evolved to a broad portfolio of open source projects up until 2015.'}, 'topics': ['keynote', 'spring'], 'room': 'Auditorium', 'timeslot': 'Wed 29th, 09:30-10:30', 'speaker': {'name': 'Juergen Hoeller', 'bio': 'Juergen Hoeller is co-founder of the Spring Framework open source project.', 'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/springjuergen', 'picture': 'http://www.springio.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/juergen_hoeller-220x220.jpeg'}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user_name\pycharmprojects\axa_experience\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 258, in get
    response = self.__base.get(headers=headers, redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user_name\pycharmprojects\axa_experience\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py", line 966, in get
    return self.__get_or_head("GET", if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user_name\pycharmprojects\axa_experience\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py", line 943, in __get_or_head
    return rq.submit(redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user_name\pycharmprojects\axa_experience\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py", line 452, in submit
    return Response.wrap(http, uri, self, rs, **response_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user_name\pycharmprojects\axa_experience\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\packages\httpstream\http.py", line 489, in wrap
    raise inst
**py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.ClientError: 404 Not Found**

Versions used:
Python - 3.8
mongoDB - 4.2.5
neo4j - 4.0.3
```

Any help in this regards, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I think the issue has to do with the version of py2neo. Mongo connector only seems to work with version 2.0.7 but when you install that version Neo4j 4.0 doesn't work with version 2.0.7. This is where I got stuck and found no solution to fix it. Maybe using Neo4J 3.0 could fix that but that wouldn't work for me as I need 4.0 for a fabric database. I've recently started looking into APOC procedures for mongodb instead. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I also see that your url is wrong it should be http://<user_name>:
  <password>@localhost:7474/db/data

Answer (score 0):

The doc-manager library you are using requires that the Mongo api-rest work, and in new versions it no longer works. If you want to use mongo version <3.2 (it has the active api rest).